# Pandas merge and grouby

Tags: python, pandas, merge, group-by

I have 2 pandas dataframes which looks like below.

```
Data Frame 1:  

Section Chainage    Frame  
R125R002    10.133  1  
R125R002    10.138  2  
R125R002    10.143  3  
R125R002    10.148  4  
R125R002    10.153  5  

Data Frame 2:

Section Chainage    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
R125R002    10.133  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.134  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.135  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.136  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.137  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.138  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.139  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.14   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.141  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.142  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.143  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.144  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.145  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.146  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.147  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.148  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.149  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.15   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.151  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.152  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.153  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

required output dataframe:

```
Section Chainage Frame  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
R125R002    10.133  1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.138  2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.143  3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.148  4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.153  5   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

Dataframe 2 has increment of 1 m interval while dataframe 1 has increment of 5 m. I would like merge dataframe 2 to dataframe 1 and apply group by.
Groupby for column 1 is sum, column 2 max, colum3 to 8 average.

In sql, I would link section between between 2 frames and apply between condition for the chainage and then add groupby.
Is there any way to achieve this in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You can first aggregate by each 5 rows with define functions in dictionary:

```
d = {'Section':'first','Chainage':'first','1':'sum','2':'max', '8':'mean'}
df22 = df2.groupby([np.arange(len(df2.index)) // 5], as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df22)
    Section  Chainage  1  2  8
0  R125R002    10.133  0  0  0
1  R125R002    10.138  0  0  0
2  R125R002    10.143  0  0  0
3  R125R002    10.148  0  0  0
4  R125R002    10.153  0  0  0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.arange(len(df2.index)) // 5)
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4]
```

And then need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df22, on=['Section','Chainage'])
print (df)
    Section  Chainage  Frame  1  2  8
0  R125R002    10.133      1  0  0  0
1  R125R002    10.138      2  0  0  0
2  R125R002    10.143      3  0  0  0
3  R125R002    10.148      4  0  0  0
4  R125R002    10.153      5  0  0  0
```

Comment: sorry Jezrael, I wasn't clear in my question. I want to aggregate the columns in data frame 2 according to dataframe 1 chainage. for an example aggregate the chainages between 10.133 and 10.138 in data frame 2 and the merge.